# Is there a way to check my devOps notification in the web app?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm starting with DevOps and I'm very surprised by many behaviours. I started created pipeline and now my email adress is flooded by emails all the time. Consequently I decided to silence email notification from my profile but now I don't know where I can see them. Is there a notification list like on any website ?